# Use \textsc for \name and \section in moderncv

Tags: sectioning, moderncv

I am trying to use `\textsc` for name and section titles in moderncv template. However, the font seems weird.

For example, looking at the following two examples, one for normal section title, one with `\textsc`:

```
\section{Education}
\section{\textsc{Education}}
```

Looks like `\textsc` also changes the default font. How can I maintain the default font at the same time have the ability to use `\textsc`? Similar problems happens in `\name` too.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

**Updated:** A MWE can be seen as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{aaa}{bbb}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{{Education}}
\section{\textsc{Education}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no sans serif small caps font with Computer Modern. Can you show a MWE?

Comment: @egreg Added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: As *egreg* mentioned, sans serif and small caps are a rather unusual combination (off the top of my head I cannot think of any of the more usual fonts providing it).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks. Is it possible to change the font only for the `\name` and `\section` part and leave other parts default?

Comment: It's possible if you know a font providing the desired combination. `moderncv` uses LatinModern fonts by default, and this font dosn't have the combination; as I said before, neither CM nor `fourier`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few sans serif typeface families with a small caps font. Latin Modern Sans, that's used by default with `moderncv`, definitely hasn't it.

So, either you change the setup so that the CV is typeset with a serif font (which isn't a bad idea, in my opinion), you have to choose a font family having the required shape. For instance,

```
\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}
```

will do, but it will typeset your CV in (a clone of) Helvetica.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

%% use \scshape in all section titles
\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\normalfont\Large\mdseries\scshape}


\name{aaa}{bbb}

\begin{document}

\show\section

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Could you please provide a list of the fonts that support the required shape?

Comment: @herohuyongtao I guess the list starts and ends with TeX Gyre Heros and TeX Gyre Adventor.

Comment: @egreg I wish, I could give you more than +1 for:

`\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\normalfont\Large\mdseries\scshape}`